# why is this considered insecure?

Tags: java, security, model-view-controller, model

Recently, i programmed a simple game in java, MVC framework, where i was told upon review by a senior programmer that it was insecure to have score ,with its getters and setters defined in the player model itself. Unfortunately, i couldn't get further info from them as to how and why it seems so, and im unable to figure out why.

Can someone please review these classes and point out why this architecture is not advisable ?

the player model:

````
public class player implements Comparable<player>{
    private int score;
    private int consecutive_misses;
    private String name;
    private int foul_count;
    private int turn;
    private boolean win;

    public player()
    {
        this.score=0;
        this.consecutive_misses=0;
        this.foul_count=0;
        this.win=false;
    }
    public void setWin(boolean win)
    {
        this.win=win;
    }
    public boolean getWin()
    {
        return this.win;
    }

    public void setPlayerName(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;

    }
    public void setTurn(int turn)
    {
         this.turn=turn;
    }

    public int getTurn()
    {
        return this.turn;
    }
    public void addScore(int score)
    {
        this.score+=score;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }


    public int getScore(){
        return this.score;
    }
     public void resetFoulCount() {
            this.foul_count = 0;
    }
     public void incrementFoulCount() {
            this.foul_count++;
    }
     public int getFoulCount()
     {
         return this.foul_count;
     }

     public void resetConsecutiveMisses() {
            this.consecutive_misses = 0;
    }
     public void incrementConsecutiveMisses() {
            this.consecutive_misses++;
    }
      public int getConsecutiveMisses()
      {
          return this.consecutive_misses;
      }
      public int compareTo(player comparePlayer)
      {
          int compareScore=((player) comparePlayer).getScore();
          return compareScore-this.score;
      }


}```

the main game model class where i implemented player model

package com.tiffany.CleanStrike_1.models;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class gameModel {

     private int player_count;
     private player[] players;
     private player current_player;
     private player winner=new player();
     private gameState game_state;
     private boolean draw=false;
     private carromBoard carrom_board;



     public gameModel(int player_count,int black_coin_count,int red_coin_count,int black_val,int red_val)
     {

         this.game_state=gameState.DORMANT;
         this.players=new player[player_count];

        for(int i=0;i<player_count;i++)
        {
            this.players[i]=new player();
        }

         this.setPlayerCount(player_count);
         Coin black_coin=new Coin(CoinColour.BLACK,black_val);
         carrom_board=new carromBoard();
         this.carrom_board.addCoin(black_coin,black_coin_count);
         Coin red_coin=new Coin(CoinColour.RED,red_val);
         this.carrom_board.addCoin(red_coin,red_coin_count);


     }

     public int getNoOfCoins(CoinColour colour)
     {
         Map<Coin,Integer> coins=new HashMap<Coin,Integer>();
            coins=this.getCoinsOnBoard();
            for(Coin coin: coins.keySet())
            {
                if(coin.getColour()==colour)
                    return coins.get(coin);
            }
         return 0;
     }

     public  void setPlayerName(int i,String name)
     {
         this.players[i].setPlayerName(name);

     }

     public  void setGameDraw()
     {
         this.draw=true;

     }
     public  boolean getGameDraw()
     {
         return this.draw;

     }
     public  void setGameState(gameState game_s)
     {
         this.game_state=game_s;
     }
     public gameState getGameState()
     {
         return this.game_state;
     }

     public int getCountOfAllCoins()
     {
         return this.carrom_board.getCountOfAllCoins();
     }

     public int getCoinValue(CoinColour colour)
     {
         for ( Coin coin : this.carrom_board.getCoins().keySet() ) {
             if(coin.getColour()==colour) {
                 return coin.getValue();
                }
            }
         return 0;

     }

     public void setWinner(player w)
     {
         this.winner=w;
     }
     public player getWinner()
     {
         return this.winner;
     }

     public void setCurrentPlayer(player p)
     {
         this.current_player=p;
     }
     public player getCurrentPlayer()
     {
         return this.current_player;
     }
     public void setPlayerCount(int count)
     {
         this.player_count=count;
     }
     public int getPlayerCount()
     {
         return this.player_count;
     }


     public Map<Coin,Integer> getCoinsOnBoard()
     {
        return this.carrom_board.getCoins();


     }
     public void removeCoin(CoinColour colour,int count)
     {
         this.carrom_board.removeCoin(colour, count);


     }
     public player[] getPlayers()
     {
         return this.players;

     }



}
````

Comment: Consider asking your question at [codereview.se]. And consider asking the senior engineer again - it's part of his job to educate more junior engineers.

Comment: Technically, if you allow setting score to a player, this means anyone who got a hold of the player can do that without other parts of the system knowing where the score came from. Scores should be distributed from a central point on your system, and should be readonly from any player's point of view. I'd even argue that score isn't a property of a player, it's something you can ask from a game or rules object. But you should absolutely ask your seniors what they mean, we aren't the ones saying current design isn't fit for purpose.

Comment: These are all valid in your code: `player.setPlayerName(null); player.setTurn(-10000); model.setWinner(new Player()); model.setCurrentPlayer(null); model.getPlayers()[0]=null;` In other words, no checking is done at all, compromising the constraints/invariants of the classes. Without ensuring these constraints, when the program crashes it's difficult to pinpoint the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class shouldn't expose it's internal structure. By exposing it's internal structure, it breaks lots of laws like Law of Demeter and other classes can take advantage of this situation and set whatever score they want. You can read more about it in the book Clean Code.